# Modify one byte of PNG file

Tags: c++, png, steganography

For my studies project, I need to modify some bytes in png file.

It's for steganography project where I have to slightly modify one byte and hide a message in a photo.

In the code below when I run it, it turns every byte to 0 and file crushes.  In bmp file it worked, but I do not know how to do that in png formats.

Unfortunately I can't use any third party libraries. I just need help with a way to read properly every byte, and later modify it using C++. Thanks for help.

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\sth....";
    fstream file(path, ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
    char buffer[1000];
    file.seekp(300);
    file << char(0);
    file.read(buffer, 1000);
    for(char c : buffer)
        cout << int(c) << " ";
```

Comment: ***It's for steganography project where I have to slightly modify one byte and hide a message in a photo*** for that you will most likely need to use a png library.

Comment: Changing a random byte in a png file will corrupt the entire png image (as you've already discovered, the hard way).  The ONLY way to safely modify the image is to 1) Convert the png to an array of "raw pixels", 2) perform your modification on the raw pixels, and finally 3) convert the pixels back to a png.  The EASIEST way to accomplish steps 1) and 3) is with a .png library.

Comment: STB has routines for simply reading and writing PNG (among other image formats): https://github.com/nothings/stb LodePNG is another: https://lodev.org/lodepng/

Comment: In addition to the png problem: An `fstream` only has a single file position for *either* reading or writing. So each time you change from reading to writing, and vice versa, you have to do a seek to the correct position.

Comment: close file after writing is done?

Answer (score 7):

The png file format uses compression, so changing bytes directly on the binary level of the file will most certainly result in a corrupted image.

You need to convert the png file format to the actual pixel values and apply steganography there.

BMP are often stored uncompressed, which makes it possible to work directly on the binary level of the file. This however is not necessarily always the case, because BMP also supports compression in form of RLE.

Comment: How about changing a byte in the header?

Comment: @Sebastian yes you could do that, but you still need to perform some parsing and apply the steganography based on the information gained from parsing. Blindly applying such changes to the binary is always problematic.